# SSRS 2012 : report builder and connection string to shared dataset

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, datasource, sql-server-2012

We are using SQL Server 2012:

- one team develops datawarehouse
- one team is in charge of reports using Report Builder

We use shared datasets.

When `.rdl` files are saved on local machine, we can see that `<ReportServerURL>` is fully embedded in file, in Shared DataSet section. How can we easily deploy the `.rdl` on another report server (production environment) without having to edit (by hand/script) all `.rdl` files?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `<ReportServerURL>` is just a hint for Report Builder. It is not used by server, so reports can be safely deployed to another report server

Comment: I'm not so sure, because we have errors! I've ended up with I've creating a simple C# app to change such URL in rdl file.